# Resolve implementation of an API dynamically

Tags: java

We have a system where we wanted to consume the implementation of our interfaces in a separate jar. The scenario is clients consume our work and provide their own implementation to override default implementation.

The question is what is the best way to bind/wire the actual implementation classes into our system?

One way is let spring wire the dependencies. It is currently not an option since all clients are not using spring.

Looked into some options like resolving interface implementation classes using reflection. Not very happy with this solution.

Another good old option is configure the class name in one of the property and let clients configure it. It looks good.

But wanted to find some elegant option if available.

Also any idea how SLF4J / EL resolves their implementations automatically?

Comment: The technique adopted by SLF4J to bind with its implementation is the dumbest, most idiotic technique imaginable in the Java language. I would not recommend it under any circumstance, except those applying to logging. BTW, I know what I am talking about since I wrote SLF4J.

Comment: Still curious about the technique, can you please share?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use [SPI (Service Provider Interface)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/spi/package-summary.html). 
It requires creating file that enumerates all available implementations of specific service. This may be annoying. Fortunately you can use this open source library that does this work for you: http://code.google.com/p/spi/

Comment: The first link in your answer makes no sense. Don't you actually want to link to [`ServiceLoader` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will look into it. But trying to avoid as much as possible using some third party API just to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library is what you are looking for.

> Reflections scans your classpath, indexes the metadata, allows you to query it on runtime and may save and collect that information for many modules within your project.
>
> Using Reflections you can query your metadata such as:
>
> - get all subtypes of some type
> - get all types/methods/fields annotated with some annotation, w/o annotation parameters matching
> - get all resources matching matching a regular expression

Comment: Good to know about this. It seems like it is a bit of over kill (caching of entire metadata etc) for my requirement. But for some systems which needs lot of metadata capabilities, it looks cool. Thanks